# How to create the uuid trigger automatically according to the parameter in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a trigger to create a uuid automatically.So I write the code like this,it compile well,but run wrong when I call it.How to fix it?

```
delimiter// 
DROP PROCEDURE  IF  EXISTS sp_uuid_auto;
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_uuid_auto(IN triggerName VARCHAR(32),
IN tableName  VARCHAR(32),IN idName  VARCHAR(32))

begin    
 drop trigger if exists triggerName;   
 set @v_sqlStr=concat('create TRIGGER ', triggerName,
' before insert on ',tableName,' FOR EACH ROW if (new.id='''' or new.id is null) then 
set new.id= REPLACE(uuid(),''-'','''');  
 end if ;');  
PREPARE statement FROM @v_sqlStr;
EXECUTE statement;
-- DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement; 
end;
 //
```

I call the procedure:`call sp_uuid_auto('tri_t_menu','t_menu','id');`

The result is :
`1295 - This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet`

Comment: Use the CONCAT function to create the string. SQL doesn't use the + to concatenate

Comment: Like said above, and also  I see double quotes in your  `@v_sqlStr`, you should have ANSI_QUOTES disabled on your database for it to work. It's safer to only use single quotes anyway, you should just **escape** them here

Comment: @ThomasG,It is still wrong.1295 - This command is not supported in the prepared statement protocol yet

Comment: From the manual - `SQL syntax for prepared statements does not support multi-statements (that is, multiple statements within a single string separated by ; characters).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html under the heading "SQL Syntax Allowed in Prepared Statements." It lists the statement types you can use in a `PREPARE`.

Following that it says:

> Other statements are not supported in MySQL 5.7.

The CREATE TRIGGER statement is not among those listed, so it falls into the "Other statements" category. You can't do CREATE TRIGGER in a PREPARE.

So you can't do this in a stored procedure. You'll have to create the trigger in your application, and format the dynamic table name *before* you submit the CREATE TRIGGER statement.